# A and X are square matrices of the same order

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A$ and $X$ are square matrices of the sme order. Given that  $\mspace{10mu}tr(AX)=0\mspace{10mu}$     if $\mspace{10mu}tr(X)=0$.

Proof that $\mspace{10mu}A\mspace{10mu}$ is a scalar matrix , i.e. $\mspace{10mu}A=\lambda I\mspace{10mu}$. $\mspace{10mu}I\mspace{10mu}- $ is identity, $\mspace{10mu}\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

I found the expression for trace   -$\mspace{20mu}C=A\cdot X \mspace{10mu},\mspace{10mu} c_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}x_{kj}\mspace{10mu},\mspace{10mu}tr(C)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{ii}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ik}x_{ki}$.

No idea what to do next

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Does it say that for any matrix $X$ which has a zero trace, that $tr(AX)=0$?  Or is it a specific $X$?

Comment: Yes, for any matrix X which has a zero trace!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $A$ is an $n \times n$ real matrix such that $\text{tr}(AX)=0$ for all $n \times n$ real matrices $X$ such that $\text{tr}(X)=0$.
Let $B = A^T - \text{tr}(A) I/n$.  Thus $\text{tr}(B) = 0$, so $\text{tr}(A B) = 0$.
Now $A = B^T + \text{tr}(A) I/n$, so 
$$ 0 = \text{tr}(AB) = \text{tr}(B^T B) + \text{tr}(A) \text{tr}(B)/n = \text{tr}(B^T B)$$
But $\text{tr}(B^T B) = \sum_i \sum_j b_{ij}^2 = 0$ implies $B = 0$, and thus $A$ is a scalar multiple of $I$.